# Docker file for mongo db

Tags: mongodb, docker

I created an RDS DB server for Mongo-DB,
which is attached to a web app, I created a Docker file for the respective Docker image & successfully deployed it in Kubernetes Pods.
Now I want to create the Docker image for this MongoDb,
Can any help me how to create a docker file to install Mongo DB & deploy my RDS server in it
Thanks in advance

Comment: `docker pull mongo` will pull official image which you can get at below link
https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to create private image for MongoDB, unless you need very specific settings.

Get the one from Docker Hub. This is the link to the official [image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo)